# Function is not being called when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my function for rendering items in a flatlist

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    var integer = Number(item.key)

    return (
        <View>
        <Text style={styles.row}>
            {item.text} 
        </Text>

        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          {this.createButtonYes(integer)}
          {this.createButtonNo(integer)}
          {this.answer(this.state.buttonStates[integer])}

        </View>

            <Text >__</Text>

        </View>
    )
  }
```

And the problem I am facing is the function this.answer is not being called when the state of buttonStates changes

```
 answer = (val) => {

    if(val){
      return(
        <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>YES</Text>
      )
    }else if(val==false){
      return(
        <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>NO</Text>
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Not Answered</Text>
      )
    }
  }
```

I assumed that every time the state changes the function would be called but that does not seem to be the case, so does anyone have a solution? What I want is whenever the buttons are pressed the state will change and then this.answer will take the changed state and display what it has to accordingly.

Thanks

EDIT:
Code for the button:

```
buttonYesHelp = num =>{
        const newItems = [...this.state.buttonStates];
        newItems[num] = true;
        return newItems
      }
      createButtonYes = (num) => {

        return(
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonYes}

          onPress =
          {
            ()=> {{this.setState({ buttonStates:this.buttonYesHelp(num) })}}
            }>
              <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>YES</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
```

num is the index of the thing I want to change in the list

EDIT:
I have tried multiple different things but the problem I keep running into is that when I render the button I want it to react to a state variable but it never seems to change based on the state even when the state is changing.
For example, in this.answer I assumed that it would return the text based on the state of buttonStates but it seems to only account for the initial state and nothing after

I was able to achieve this in a different piece of code with identical syntax but for some reason this is not working

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire code from which you took that first function? (what the state looks like, the button that's supposed to update the state..)

Comment: And where the state change, like `this.setState({})`

Comment: $100 says you're mutating `this.state.buttonStates` instead of setting it. Show the code where you set the state (`createButtonYes` and `createButtonNo`). [Don't mutate state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state). Don't mutate state is the answer to 90% of the react/redux questions on SO

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza I added the button component with the onPress that changes the state

Comment: @高鵬翔 I added the onPress that changes the state

Comment: @Adam I created a copy of the buttonStates and then changed the copy. After, I set the state of buttonStates to the copy